# What does * means in WCF

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, wcf

What is meant when declaring a WCF service as :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "*")]
```

that is using the * instead of POST or GET

and what is the difference between it and POST or GET.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means any [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods): `POST`, `GET`, `PUT`, `DELETE` etc.

Having `Method = "POST"` would mean the method is only accessible on an `HTTP POST`.

Likewise `Method = "GET"` would only be available on an `HTTP GET`.

Comment: will this affect the data to be sent ? as I know that POST and GET differs in the way they recieve/send messages

Comment: That depends on the spec of the method, like if you see [`DELETE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE) it shows `Request has body: No` which makes it similar to a `GET` which also has no request body. A `PUT` and `POST` are similar in that they have request bodies. The methods are just meant for different things, but that's a different question that you should research.